# Change the optional arguments in the interval package

Tags: pgfkeys

A half-open interval can be typeset using `\interval[open left]{a}{b}` from the `interval` package. But the option `open left` is very long. Is it possible to use a contraction such as `\interval[ol]{a}{b}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{interval}

\intervalconfig{
  ol/.style={open left},
}

\begin{document}

$\interval[ol]{a}{b}$

$\interval[open left]{a}{b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but it is easier not exactly as you are suggesting:

`\def\iol{\interval[open left]}` with usage `\iol{a}{b}`.

Certainly, the name you will use should be easy for you, but `\iol` seems to be the shortest, easy to remeber one.